# Bypass RStudion login screen

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I am trying to setup a link from the a web application into RStudio Professional. The Web application is already authenticated the USER. Today, when the user clicks on RStudio launch link it takes him to a login screen. This is repetitive as the user has already logged in to the app. How can I bypass the RStudio login screen and take the user directly into R Studio?  Are there any API's or any authentication mechanism to bypass R login screen?

Comment: Probably a better question over at community.rstudio.com

Comment: Thanks Phil, I have also posted in RStudio Community. Will try my luck here as well.